# How to issue a find command using MongoDB C# Driver with native JSON criteria syntax?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there any way that I can issue a "find" command to a MongoDB collection thru the C# driver that uses the native json criteria syntax and not LINQ or QUeryBuilder syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
var json = "{'_id': 3456}";
var doc= BsonDocument.Parse(json);
var query = new QueryDocument(doc);
var result = coll.Find(query);
```

Comment: If I had read this before following the "Duplicate question" link I would have saved 30 minutes of work.